# Prevent the last child from having styled be applied

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to prevent the last child from having backgroundColor added. The reset box needs to stay white. I don't want to give the reset box a different class just to prevent it from changing color. I need to have the styles not be added. Any help or push in the right direction would be much appreciated. I tried using :not(:last-child) but that didn't seem to work.

```
$(".btn").click(function () {
  boxColor = $(this).val();
$(".box:not(:last-child)").css('background-color', boxColor);
});
```

Heres my code:

```js
$(".btn").click(function () {
  boxColor = $(this).val();
  $(".box").css('background-color', boxColor);
});

$(".reset").click(function () {
  $(".box").removeAttr('style');
});
```

```css
body {
  background: lightgrey;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-direction: row;
  max-width: 980px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.col-3 {
  flex: 0 0 24.999%;
}

.box {
  height: 200px;
  max-width: 230px;
  margin: 1em;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.box.red {
  background: #E53A40;
}
.box.green {
  background: #285943;
}
.box.blue {
  background: #6AAFE6;
}
.box.white {
  background: white;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .col-3 {
    flex: 0 0 100%;
  }

  .box {
    max-width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
  }
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-3">
      <div class="box red">
        <button class="btn" value="#E53A40">Red</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
      <div class="box green">
        <button class="btn" value="#285943">Green</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
      <div class="box blue">
        <button class="btn" value="#6AAFE6">Blue</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
      <div class="box white">
        <button class="reset" id="reset">Reset</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The question is not about how to not select the `:last-child` because here it's not about sibling elements and it's not about CSS selector but jQuery selector

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`:last`](https://api.jquery.com/last-selector/) instead. The `:last-child` CSS selector consider elements inside the **same container**:

> The `:last-child` CSS pseudo-class represents **the last element** among a
>   group of **sibling elements**.<sup>[ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child)</sup>

```js
$(".btn").click(function () {
  boxColor = $(this).val();
$(".box:not(:last)").css('background-color', boxColor);
});

$(".reset").click(function () {
  $(".box").removeAttr('style');
});
```

```css
body {
  background: lightgrey;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-direction: row;
  max-width: 980px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.col-3 {
  flex: 0 0 24.999%;
}

.box {
  height: 200px;
  max-width: 230px;
  margin: 1em;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.box.red {
  background: #E53A40;
}
.box.green {
  background: #285943;
}
.box.blue {
  background: #6AAFE6;
}
.box.white {
  background: white;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .col-3 {
    flex: 0 0 100%;
  }

  .box {
    max-width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
  }
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-3">
      <div class="box red">
        <button class="btn" value="#E53A40">Red</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
      <div class="box green">
        <button class="btn" value="#285943">Green</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
      <div class="box blue">
        <button class="btn" value="#6AAFE6">Blue</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
      <div class="box white">
        <button class="reset" id="reset">Reset</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should just use the `:last` element selector on your query.

I think you also might want to just set background color to none instead of removing the whole style attribute, just in case you want to add more css styles to the elements in the future that shouldn't be reset.

```
$(".btn").click(function () {
  boxColor = $(this).val();
$(".box:not(:last)").css('background-color', boxColor);
});

$(".reset").click(function () {
  $(".box").css('background-color', 'none');
});
```